# check output of a script before running

Tags: bash, shell-script, centos

I have a bash script that do some Database Jobs. parts of this script:

```
DBNAME_ARRAY=( mydb1 mydb2 )  
DB2PATH=/bin/db2
BACKUPLOGPATH=/data1/`date +%y-%m-%d`_BACKUP.out 
IP=170.10.20.11 
.
.
for DBNAME in "${DBNAME_ARRAY[@]}"
do
BACKUPSQL="BACKUP DATABASE $DBNAME TO /dbdata1/${DBNAME,,}Backup"
$DB2PATH connect to $DBNAME 
.
.
```

before i execute this i want to know if variables are placed in every line correctly. is this possible?
for example i want something like this:

```
  BACKUP DATABASE mydb1 TO /dbdata1/mtdb1Backup
  /bin/db2 connect to mydb1 
  BACKUP DATABASE mydb1 TO /dbdata2/mtdb1Backup
  /bin/db2 connect to mydb2
```

after i check that everything is correct i run them.

Comment: Where is your rest of the script? There is nothing beyond `BACKUPSQL` initialization  in your code shown

Comment: @Inian its about 200 lines. its just part of it. should i add more lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you are constructing an SQL statement, or a list of SQL statements, that you will give to a database server.  Instead of invoking the command that would execute the statements on the server, output the statements to the terminal.

If your original command was

```
some_db_command "$backupsql"
```

then you could replace this by

```
printf '%s\n' "$backupsql"
```

If the script then goes on to do other things that may depend on the execution of those SQL commands, then insert an `exit` before that happens. You are only interested in seeing the SQL commands that would have been sent to the database server.

Comment: you mean something like `printf '%s\n' "$DB2PATH connect to $DBNAME"` ?

Comment: @BlackCrystal I mean that you print whatever commands that you are interesting in seeing (instead of executing them live).  This is pretty ordinary "debug by print" procedure. You output things to the terminal to make sure they are correct.

Comment: i would have done this debug for every section of this script if i was writhing it. since i didn't write it now i should review allllllllllll lines and add `printf`.